# Booking System Avoiding Double Insertion Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, race-condition

Say I have a column in Postgresql DB like this to represent booking system for desk in an office. In a day, a person can only book a desk.

| ID | Booked_Date | Seat_ID | Employee_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-08 | 10C | id1 |
| 2 | 2022-07-08 | 20C | id2 |

When booking a desk, the system need to check whether that person has booked any other desk or other person has booked that desk before inserting the booking data. So, something like this for example:

```
select count(*) as today_book from booking where (booked_date=today and seat_id='10C')
or (booked_date=today and employee_id='id1')

if(today_book == 0) {
    insert into booking values(today, book_seat, current_employee_id)
}
```

To avoid duplicate data (a desk booked by more than one person), how can I do it in Postgresql? I am using Postgresql 11.xx version.
I am thinking about using Plpgsql or stored procedure and wrapped around above logic in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need two unique constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT seat_unique_per_day
   UNIQUE (booked_date, seat_id);
ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT employee_unique_per_day
   UNIQUE (booked_date, employee_id);
```

Then you simply try to `INSERT` and catch and handle constraint violation errors in your application.